# Barn door with one of the bolts on drywall

Tags: drywall, doors, safety, studs, interior

I just installed a barn door track on a nice, solid piece of timber. However, the piece of timber doesn't go all the way horizontally, meaning that the last bolt is just on the drywall (plasterboard), like the diagram I made on this image I took from internet:

[image]

I know you'll say *"find a stud"*, but there's none up to the next wall. My reasoning is that 4 bolts are on solid timber and just 1 is on drywall, so the door should not collapse. What do you think, is that safe?

Comment: `what do you think?` ... opinion based questions are off topic here

Comment: If you temporarily remove the bolt fastened to the plasterboard, how solid does the rail feel?  That would give an indication of how much it relies on all fastenings being securely mounted.

Comment: It probably be okay since you are not going to be hanging from the door when it is at that end.  There should be studs at the end of the door frame so I would be seeing if the last mounting bolt can be moved a bit, maybe by drilling a new hole in the track.

Comment: @HandyHowie solid enough for me to do a chin-up. Thanks for your comments.